# Error in meta tag description in Google SERP (Yoast pluggin on Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, seo, metadata, meta-tags

I am using YOAST plugin for SEO on my Wordpress website. I have a multilingual websites (one language/subdomain) using WPML plugin.

SEO settings in my website and homepage is correctly set and I can find my website correctly when I type keywords on Google search engine.

However I found an error:

When I type "http://www.mywebsite.com" in the search engines, the Google search results shows me a wrong meta description snippet (from a blog post) and wrong sitelinks (one including a a page from a subdomain language).

How can I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For correct it's you can use Google webmaster Tools : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Google list most used pages as "Sitelinks" when you search your root domain. This pages and folders usually generated automatically by Google.

However you are able to remove, or manually add this links from Google Webmaster Tools.

Follow this steps :
Login or Sign up Google Webmaster Tools. Add your site and verify. Click on your domain name at Search console. And in the left menu click on Search Appearance find "Sitelinks" in this menu

Google Webmaster Tools > click on your domain > Search Appearance > Sitelinks

In this section you can use "Demote this sitelink URL" and Change or remove Sitelinks. Or you can offer new one.